# Dwscript web server

Tags: delphi, webserver, dwscript

I want to use dwscript for web programming ( generating dynamic content). I was wondering if there is any module for apache web server? Or how can I run my own web server based on dwscript?

Comment: "i was wondering if there is any module for apache web server ?" from what I know, there isn't any, I'm actually working on one, soon to be released under Apache License 2.0, if you can wait a few months, it will use DWS as it's primary language (:

Comment: it's not easy, there are many things to be taken into consideration and my time is limited... but that doesn't mean you can't start working on it (:

Comment: I know it's not a trivial task any way i think is a great ideea for us pascal fans. keep up the good work!

Comment: If a simple TWebModule is enough for you, you can slap up one using Delphi's Wizard and call DWScript from there with the HTML filter. That'll get you basic ISAPI capability quickly.
More time-intensive is hooking all the web requests/responses properties, especially as TWebModule is quite limited in that regard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not (yet?) familiar with DWScript, but I've created an Apache module that runs a Delphi-compiled module that serves a web-site over an abstract interface, so it can plug into IIS or InternetExplorer also. There are also versions that auto-recompile when it detects changes to the source-code, so you can develop and test by hitting refresh in the browser window:

http://xxm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: -1: This doesn't answer the question asked. Perhaps it would be better as a comment.

Comment: You might be right. I thought this would fit as answer if I read the question a little more expanded to 'can you do dynamic content on Apache with Delphi'. If you do, I feel Eric Grange's comment should be an answer here too.
Then again, Dorin asked me if he could use parts of xxm to build his DWScript platform, so who knows in time this might still turn out to be an acceptable answer.